# Limit the number of rows counted in in google data studio

Tags: looker-studio, google-search-console

I have a scorecard that looks at the number of URL clicks driven by all queries which works as expected. I am now trying to display the number of clicks driven by the top 10 queries in the scorecard. I was able to limit the number of rows in my table by disabling pagination to show only the top 10 queries but now I'm looking to sum the clicks in a scorecard to provide a quick summary rather than having a table.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what you want to do is possible dynamically via just the Search Console connector. [Google Data Studio does not provide any way to calculate rankings](https://support.google.com/datastudio/thread/4952223?hl=en) via calculated fields, so there's no way for you to know which query is in the top 10 without looking at a sorted table. A few imperfect alternatives (roughly in order of increasing complexity):

- You apply a filter so that the score card only aggregates values above a certain threshold. This would be hardcoded, so you would be filtering on the Clicks (ie aggregate all URL clicks above 100)
- You apply a filter to the score card so that it only aggregates clicks from the top 10 URLs. This would not be a dynamically updating filter, so you'd have to look at the table to see which URLs are in the top 10, which would change as time goes on. This would end up being a filter like: "Include URLS Contains www.google.com,www.stackoverflow.com"
- If you do not mind using google sheets as an intermediary, you could dump your Search Console data into a spreadsheet so that you can manipulate it however you like and then use the spreadsheet as the data source for data studio (as opposed to the Search Console connector). [It looks like there might be some addons out there that you can use out of the box](https://searchanalyticsforsheets.com/) although I haven't used it myself, so not sure how difficult it is. Alternatively, you can build something out yourself via the Google Script and the [Search Console API](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api-original/v3?apix=true)
- You could build a custom [Data Studio Community Visualization](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/visualization). (BTW just because they are called 'Community Visualizations' does not mean you have to make them publicly available.) Essentially here, you would be building a scorecard like component that aggregates the data according to your own rules, although this does require more coding experience. (Before you build one, check if something like what you need exists in the [gallery](https://datastudio.google.com/gallery?category=visualization), but at a quick glance, I don't see anything that would meet your needs.)